# Lots of Internet browsing issues, all browsers

Tags: 11.04, usb, browser, modem

Before the upgrade, everything was working fine. Now, however, I can connect to the Internet but a lot of stuff fails, and the weirdest thing is that it happens with Firefox, Chromium and Opera. Some of the things that fail:

- I can't log in to Stack Overflow, after entering user/pass it loads for a long time on Firefox and throws Error 408 (browser request timed out) on Chromium and Opera
- I can't log in to Hotmail, similar symptoms
- I can login to Facebook, but when I try to write a comment, or just post something in my wall, it stays loading for a long time, and then fails

The first two issues seem to be related to secure pages, and the second one is another issue altogether, I believe. However, they all happen with all browsers, which is really weird.

Talking about weird: I connect using a Huawei SmartAX MT 810 USB modem, which cost me blood and tears to get it working under Ubuntu. I ordered an ethernet modem/router with my ISP, and I'm still waiting, but this issue intrigues me anyway. Has anyone experienced this kind of problems? I Googled around, but couldn't find a similar case.

Comment: Firefox crashes on startup a lot for me, and pages in chrome crash a lot too.

Comment: @Jcubed: that should be unrelated to this question. If you think it's worth a new question, do so, but include details like error messages and logs (`/var/log/kern.log` and maybe `~/.xsession-errors`, even better: start `firefox` from the command line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 3 comps 2 of which was having this same issue didn't matter what Operating System i had installed still did same thing. I Found a Bios Update that Fixed my issue . Check if your computer has a  Bios update on the manufacturers Website.

- Make sure to read the change history of the bios updates these was the change history on my machines  `Change History`

  Version 2.30 - 2010-01-22
      Updated the AMD logo displayed while booting up.
      Updated the Computrace option ROM to fix an issue where the Video and Touchpad devices disappear intermittently in Windows7 when Computrace was enabled.
      Fixed: HD audio device disappears in 64-bit operating systems with 4GB of system RAM when waking from Sleep mode.
  Version 2.00 - 2008-06-20
      Added: Samsung and LG panel support (LTN154AT07-T01, LP154WX4-TLC8).
      Added: Brightness tables for new panels.
  Version 1.90 - 2008-02-29
      Corrected an intermittent black screen issue.
  Version 1.80 - 2007-11-08
      The memory bus frequency was set to the PC2-5300 specification based on AMD recommendation.
      A chipset register was modified to fine tune WLAN performance based on AMD recommendation.
  I hope this helps.